# How to visualise an error if checkbox is not ticked

Tags: r, shiny

I've created a shiny app mirroring a survey form with data stored online. Data is not submitted if the checkbox (tick) is not ticked (tick == F). However, I cannot find a way to visualise a prompt/error to let the user know that they have not submitted data because they have not ticked the checkbox.

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets4)
library(shinyvalidate)
library(shinyFeedback)

table <- "responses"
SHEET_ID <- ### google form here

saveData <- function(data) {
  data <- data %>% as.list() %>% data.frame()
  sheet_append(SHEET_ID, data)
}

loadData <- function() {
  read_sheet(SHEET_ID)
}

fields <- c("name", "email", "tick")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyFeedback(),
    textInput("name", "Your name:", ""),
    textInput("email", "Your email address:", ""),
    checkboxInput("tick", "I am sure.", FALSE),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })
    
    iv <- InputValidator$new()
    iv$add_rule("email", 
                sv_email(message = "Please enter a valid email address.",
                         allow_na = F))
    iv$enable()
    
    observeEvent(input$submit, 
                 if(input$tick == F) {
                 } else {
                   saveData(formData())
                 }
    )
    
    session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
  }
)
```

Also, how can I visualise (and store) the result of the following code after "submit" has been pressed? I don't know where this should be implemented.

```
final_message <- sample(c('Many thanks!', 'Thanks!', 'Merci!'), 1, replace = F)
print(final_message)
```

Any advice on how to improve the code (and make it neater) is welcome, it's my first attempt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately **shinyFeedback** does not work for checkboxes. You can use **shinyvalidate** as follows:

```r
    iv <- InputValidator$new()
    iv$add_rule("email", 
                sv_email(message = "Please enter a valid email address.",
                         allow_na = FALSE))
    iv$add_rule("tick",
                sv_equal(TRUE, 
                         message_fmt = "Check before submit!"))
    iv$enable()
```

You can use the Shiny function `showNotification` to throw a message, regarding your other question. Or, better, the [**shinyToastify** package](https://github.com/stla/shinyToastify):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyvalidate)
library(shinyToastify)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyToastify(), ##### <- don't forget that!
    textInput("name", "Your name:", ""),
    textInput("email", "Your email address:", ""),
    checkboxInput("tick", "I am sure.", FALSE),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    iv <- InputValidator$new()
    iv$add_rule("email", 
                sv_email(message = "Please enter a valid email address.",
                         allow_na = FALSE))
    iv$add_rule("tick",
                sv_equal(TRUE, 
                         message_fmt = "Check before submit!"))
    iv$enable()
    
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      if(iv$is_valid()) {
        showToast(
          session, input, 
          text = "Fine!", type = "success"
        )
        # do something here
      } else {
        showToast(
          session, input, 
          text = "Some inputs are not valid!", type = "error"
        )
      }
    })
    
  }
  
)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I have updated the code as you suggested!